# Questions regarding Hive to HBase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I saw an external Hive table stored data for HBase:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS ods.demo_table(
    rowkey String COMMENT 'rowkey of hbase',
    ....
    )
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "info:...") TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "...", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "...")
;
```

I have the several questions:

1. What is the HDFS path of this table?

This Hive external `create` sentence does not comprise `location` and the HDFS path `/user/hive/warehouse/ods.db/demo_table` does not exists. So where to find the data file of this table?

In addition, if there exists a default path for the `HBaseStorageHandler`, where to find and change it? the config file?

2. How does HBase know that this table is linked to Hive (its HBase create sentence does not comprise such info) and where is the location?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive-HBase integration we are creating a **sql wrapper table(hive)** on top of **no sql table(hbase)** by defining schema and mapping the table/cf while creating Hive table using HBaseStorageHandler.

Hive table is just a wrapper around hbase table and all the actual data is still stored in HBase table.

---

> 1.What is the HDFS path of this table?

---

You need to go to hbase-site.xml to find out the hbase table locations.

```
 <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://nn:8020/apps/hbase</value>
 </property>
```

default location to HBase tables is **/apps/hbase** and if your hbase table created in default name space then

```
bash$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hbase/data/data/default/<table_name>/
```

**(or)**

If the HBase table created in specific name space then

```
bash$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hbase/data/data/<name_space_name>/<table_name>/
```

Once you list the files in the directory then you are able to see Hfiles located in the directory, which will have all the hbase table data.

1. If we are using **create external table statement then the table is managed by
   HBase** and HBase table needs to be exist before we are creating a
   hive table.
2. If we are using **create table statement then the table is managed by Hive**
   and hive creates table in HBase and table should be exist before in
   HBase.

The storage handler is built as an independent module, hive-hbase-handler-x.y.z.jar and you will find this jar in hive-client lib directory.

> 2.> How does HBase know that this table is linked to Hive (its HBase
>    create sentence does not comprise such info) and where is the
>    location?

As hive table is pointing to HBase table using HbaseStoragehandler and reading the HBase data with a schema.
 While creating hive table we are defining which table/cf to point to in HBase.

For more detailed info refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) link regarding HBase-Hive Integration.